# ¿Cómo puedo extraer la desviación estándar de los efectos aleatorios de una modelisation conjointe (jointModel)?

Tags: r

**CREACION DEL MODELO (Package ‘JM’)**

1. Creacion del modelo mixto con efectos aleatorios

```
mod_mml=lme(MDRD~DELAI_MONTH, data=Mixed, random=~1+DELAI_MONTH|N_ID,na.action=na.exclude)
```

2. Transformacion en formato largo de los datos de riesgos competitivos (transplante y muerte)

```
SurvieCR=crLong(Survie,"Statut1_60m","Vivant 60m")
```

3. Modelo de supervivencia utilisando el formato largo incluyendo el incluir el indicador de riesgos competitivos como factor de estratificación

```
Surv_comp=coxph(Surv(DELAI_M,status2) ~ 1*strata + strata(strata),
                data=SurvieCR, x=TRUE,method="efron",na.action=na.exclude)
```

4. Modelo conjunto correspondiente se ajusta simplemente incluyendo los dos submodelos anteriores como argumentos principales, estableciendo el argumento CompRisk en TRUE que corresponde al riesgo competitivo

```
JM_comp=jointModel(mod_mml, Surv_comp, timeVar="DELAI_MONTH",
                   method="spline-PH-aGH",
                   interFact=list(value= ~ strata, data=SurvieCR)
                   CompRisk=TRUE)
```

5. Codigo que me luestra los resultados

```
summary(JM_comp)
random.effects(JM_comp)
coef(JM_comp) 
coef(JM_comp, process = "Longitudinal") ....etc
```

6. Exemplo de los resultados

```
 random.effects(JM_comp)
     (Intercept)   DELAI_MONTH
1    3.727740214 -0.2020818077
2    1.070965087  0.0370529800
3    3.440276448  0.1582811172
4   -4.551210225 -0.1568204062
5   -2.943917109 -0.0389127841
```

7.pero necesito la desviación estándar de cada intersección y de cada pendiente. si alguien me puede ayudar le quedo agradecida